# echo Error on for Page Protected PHP page

Tags: php

I have a protected page that requires you to login to access the page content.

Where can I put an else statement that echos "wrong username or wrong password"

if the user does not enter the exact user/password?

The PHP page

```
<?php
    // Define your username and password 
    $username = "user"; 
    $password = "password"; 
    if ($_POST['txtUsername'] != $username || $_POST['txtPassword'] != $password) { 
?> 
    <h1>Login</h1> 
    <form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> 
        <label>User</label>
        <input type="text" title="Enter your Username" name="txtUsername" />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" title="Enter your password" name="txtPassword" />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" />
    </form> 
<?php
    } 
    else {
?> 
    <p>This is the protected page. Your private content goes here.</p> 
<?php
    }
?>
```

** I have tried entering it after -- else {  at the bottom of page

** I have tried entering it after -- if($_POST...$password) {

neither one worked.  I attached a image to show you what I mean.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: First of all you need `AJAX` for that! Since you need to call the script again to check for the values and `echo`.

Comment: dear for your first problem simply use empty like if(empty) than echo the message

Comment: @DOCASAREL that's a really dumb suggestion.. why would ajax help at all?

Comment: You don't necessarily need ajax but you barely have any logic contained on this page to do anything. No db check or anything...

Comment: @Ben Haw? To get state? Or you want to reload every time you check? But you could do that. Rasclatt's comment much more undumb.

Comment: @DOC ASAREL Thanks, I feel better that I am less dumb.... :D

Comment: @Rasclatt Hehe, only your comment is. Looking at our both reputation we should consider both none. ;)

Comment: Well it is arguable that you "need" ajax, but one does "need" logic to produce a result...and this here example has little logic...

Comment: @rasclatt he already declare you dumb lesser one, are you not happy, even though you were right when you commented, is like getting a negative score on the right answer, its funny na

Comment: I am going to update my facebook status..."I am much more undumb today...and proud of it."

Comment: You're ***not going LIVE*** with this I hope.

Comment: @Fred -ii-, It's not live for any website. It is a learning tool that I am using to understand PHP better. Although, I sometimes wonder if retailers use this with as much data that is always stolen :)

Comment: @Rasclatt, You cant use it for your facebook, I have the trademark on less undumb today than yesterday. although mine says, less undumberer too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can also be solved by simply setting some validation flags and using those on your views. Using your own code structure template, the following might do the trick:

```
<?php 

// Define your username and password 
$username = "user"; 
$password = "password"; 

$hasError = true;
$hasSubmitted = false;

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $hasSubmitted = true;

    if ($_POST['txtUsername'] != $username || $_POST['txtPassword'] != $password) { 
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $hasError = false;
    }
}

if ($hasError):
?>
<h1>Login</h1> 

<?php if ($hasSubmitted): ?>
<p>*You entered a wrong username or password</p>
<?php endif; ?>
<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> 
<label>User</label><input type="text" title="Enter your Username" name="txtUsername" />
<label>Password</label><input type="password" title="Enter your password" name="txtPassword" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" />
</form> 

<?php else: ?>

<p>This is the protected page. Your private content goes here.</p> 

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: you are welcome @AlwaysLearning, you probably already know but just a heads up - you need to validate the user inputs, make your credentials more secure, The usual stuff you walk through before pushing to production or live.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    class   ValidateUser
        {
            public static   function Check($user,$pass)
                {
                    $settings[] =   ($user == $_POST['txtUsername'])? 1:0;
                    $settings[] =   ($pass == $_POST['txtPassword'])? 1:0;

                    return (array_sum($settings) == 2)? true:false;
                }
        }

    // if the username and passowrd match up
    if(isset($_POST['txtUsername'])) {
            $uservalid  = ValidateUser::Check('hardcodeuser','hardcodepass');
        }

    // If user/pass not valid
    if($uservalid !== true || !isset($uservalid)) { ?> 
        <h1>Login</h1> 
        <?php if(isset($uservalid) && $uservalid !== true) echo 'Invalid Login'; ?>
        <form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> 
            <label>User</label>
            <input type="text" title="Enter your Username" name="txtUsername" />
            <label>Password</label><input type="password" title="Enter your password" name="txtPassword" />
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" />
        </form> 

<?php } 
    else { ?> 
    <p>This is the protected page. Your private content goes here.</p>
    <?php 
        } ?>
```

Comment: thanks @Rasclatt. Let me work on this one. I dont want to use database at this point, just a username on page. It will be checked on the page.

Comment: So you are hardcoding a username and password and just checking against that?

Comment: yes. I am not using a database at the moment. just hard code user/pass

Comment: Try this validator class. In the `ValidateUser::Check('hardcodeuser','hardcodepass')` you need to change your username and password here. Hopefully you don't have anything important you are trying to do because this here stuff is not very safe...

Comment: thanks for your help! No this is not live per a users website, it is a test that i am doing to teach myself php. There are free codes out there that already exist for this stuff. But I am trying to live it, not copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Define your username and password
$username = "user";
$password = "password";

$loginPageTPL = <<< EOF
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1> 

<form name="form" method="post" action="{% PHP_SELF %}"> 
{% ERROR_MESSAGES %}
<label for="username">User</label>
<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Username" name="txtUsername" />
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" name="txtPassword" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" />
</form> 
</body>
</html>
EOF;

$loginPageTPL = str_replace('{% PHP_SELF %}', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $loginPageTPL);

if ((isset($_POST['txtUsername'])) && (isset($_POST['txtPassword']))) {
    if (($_POST['txtUsername'] == $username) && ($_POST['txtPassword'] == $password)) {
        echo "your private content here";
        return;
    } else {
        $loginPageTPL = str_replace('{% ERROR_MESSAGES %}', '<div style="color: red">* you entered a wrong username and password</div>', $loginPageTPL);
        echo $loginPageTPL;
    }
} else {
    $loginPageTPL = str_replace('{% ERROR_MESSAGES %}', '', $loginPageTPL);
    echo $loginPageTPL;
}
```

Comment: yeah the logic was flawed, early in the morning before bed ;) updating now. Thing is, you don't do that anymore, bad bad bad. You either send out an encrypted cookie if user, pwhash match or send out a jwt if matched. I wanted to introduce you to templates. You have a template string, replace placeholders, some templates eval the php code in the templates (which I don't think is good from a security perspective), and finally the edited template string is output.

Comment: also you have 2 handlers (or php scripts). one for checking login and another checking the cookie or jwt and returning the protected resource. So this logic is really just for learning/comprehension purposes, you don't do stuff like this in the real world (and if you do, bad bad bad shame on you).

Answer (score 0):

Try this and read the comment in the code

```
    <?php 
    if ($_POST['txtUsername'] != $username || $_POST['txtPassword'] != $password) { 

    ?> 

    <h1>Login</h1> 

    <form name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> 
    <label>User</label><input type="text" title="Enter your Username" name="txtUsername" />
    <label>Password</label><input type="password" title="Enter your password" name="txtPassword" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" />
    </form> 

    <?php 

//adde these line to check weather its empty or not    
if(!empty($_POST['txtUsername']) && empty($_POST['txtPassword']))
        {
        //this is complicated part you need check username and password. and they have to 
//match. 
// i cant help you here, cause i dont know from where you want to check username and password
//but i am giving you if statement.
//simple way you get the username from form, than check wether the username password matches, in the db or not, and if does not matches, we show the error message
//run the query
//check the result
//result return succes then ok
//else show the error
        }
        else 
            {
        echo 'You need to enter your username and password';
    }

    } 
    else { 

    ?> 

    <p>This is the protected page. Your private content goes here.</p> 

    <?php 

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: I am currently just checking the username/password on the same page as the content for this project. thanks

Comment: @AlwaysLearning so you want me update the answer according to you requirment, if you want i cant do that, Thanks let me know